# Does Magento Version 1.5.0.1 requires SUPEE-6788?

Tags: magento-1.5

I am not able to find SUPEE-6788 for Magento version 1.5.0.1, does that mean we don't need for this version?

Comment: You can refer to this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87957/does-magento-1-4-1-1-require-patch-supee-6788